# how to generate dynamic id using variable and delete the element using the same variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, frontend

Hi i am creating a small web application where if i click create element it should create new button using variable x. When i click the remove element it should delete from the last element until no new element should be there.

But the problem is when i click create element i am not able to add id to the newly created element dynamically.At the same time how can i delete using variable as id to delete new element.

Here element means Button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
var x=1;
var fd,d;
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#r").click(function(){
$("#fd").remove();

});

$("#c").click(function(){

var txt="<div id='fd"+x+"'><button > New Button </button></div>";
x++;
$("#d").after(txt);

});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="c">Create Element</button>
<button id="r">Remove Element</button>
<br> <br>
<div id="fd">
<button id="d">First Element</button>
</div>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

[I have included the image where i am able to create new element but not able to delete it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taPp6.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a common class to each new element and then use `last()` filter with that class to remove the last one

```js
var x = 1;
var fd, d;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#r").click(function() {
    $(".button").last().remove();

  });

  $("#c").click(function() {

    var txt = "<div class='button' id='fd" + x + "'><button > New Button </button></div>";
    x++;
    $("#d").after(txt);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="c"> Create Element </button>
<button id="r"> Remove Element </button> <br>
<br>
<div id="fd">
  <button id="d"> First Element </button>
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but still i want to delete with id not with the class.

Comment: Based on what criteria? You only have one button and a group of elements. How do you intend to match them to the click event?

Comment: I am not able to create a dynamic id using variable x . Using the variable fd1, fd2,fd3 ....i need to delete the element “$(#variable).remove; is it possible.

Comment: yes if you want to do that by clicking on each of the new buttons. Is that what you want?

Comment: Consider i created a new element using create element. Then id are fd1 fd2 fd3 etc... but when i click remove element for $(#fd2).remove() . My button is not deleted. I hope u understand my problem. Id is not created.